# What is the difference between timers.startSingleTimer and scheduler.scheduleOnce in Akka Actor?

Tags: scala, akka, scheduling, actor

I am designing an actor that should schedule sending a message to itself.

I notice that there are at least two ways to do it.

I would like to understand the difference to choose the right one.

**The first is one method of akka.actor.Timers:**

```
def startSingleTimer(key: Any, msg: Any, timeout: FiniteDuration): Unit
```

**The second is the pretty common way with scheduler of actor context system:**

```
final def scheduleOnce(
    delay:    FiniteDuration,
    receiver: ActorRef,
    message:  Any)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext,
                            sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Cancellable
```

**Question:**

- Which is the main difference between them in case of scheduling a
  message to itself?
- Is it a good idea to pass actor context to `scheduleOnce` method?

Comment: Timers are not thread-safe. It may play difference if you want to use both futures and cancel some timers (because lack of thread-safety means that reference to your timer may be lost).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**akka.actor.Timers.startSingleTimer**

- Can be used only within an actor
- Allows *only* scheduling a message to self, ie not possible to schedule a message to some other actors
- If actor dies, the active timers are cancelled automatically
- Keeps track of active timers by user provided `key`

**context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce**

- Can be used to schedule messages outside and inside actors
- Requires explicit `ActorRef` for `receiver` and optional `sender`
- There is no automatic clean-up process. All should be handled explicitly by calling returned `akka.actor.Cancellable`

So, if you just need to schedule messages to itself, pick `akka.actor.Timers`

> Is it a good idea to pass actor context to scheduleOnce method?

Not sure in what way you want to do it, but in general actor context must be used only within `receive` method and not passed outside of an actor neither used in callback methods of `Futures`.